# Wrong result by ":arith.euclidean_solver true"

Tags: z3

[This smt2 script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9tdeyyc27c2zkq/euclidean_solverTrue.smt2?dl=0) gives `unsat` if I use
`(check-sat-using (then simplify solve-eqs (repeat bit-blast) (! smt :bv.enable_int2bv true :arith.euclidean_solver true)))`, and gives `sat` if I remove `:arith.euclidean_solver true`. The expected result is `sat`.
Z3 version 4.4.0

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a bug on github to track this.
The URL is: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/100